# Given $A=\alpha + M$ and $B = \beta + M$, show that either $A=B$ or $A\cap B = \varnothing$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $M$ be a subspace of the vector space $V$, and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be any two vectors in $V$. Given $A=\alpha + M$ and $B = \beta  + M$, show that either $A=B$ or $A\cap B = \varnothing$.

Well, if we presume $A=B$, since $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $V$, then I can try an element proof to show that there is an element of $A$ that is in $B$ and vice versa. However given any element $\alpha + M \in A$ and $\beta + M \in B$, I am not sure how to use the common link, $M$, to show that the elements are the same.

I think past this hurdle, $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and showing that $(\alpha + \beta) + M$ are fairly trivial to show though.

What is implied when you can add a subspace $M$ to a vector $\alpha$ when they share the same vector space?

Comment: The title is very hard to understand without reading the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$ and let $u \in A\cap B$.
Then there are $m, n \in M$ such that $u = m + \alpha = n+\beta$.
It follows that $m-n = \beta - \alpha$.
Of course, because $M$ is a subspace and $m,n\in M$, $m-n \in M$.

Let $a \in A$ and write $a = v + \alpha$.
Observe that
$$a = v - (m+n) + (m-n) + \alpha = \big(v -(m+n)\big) + \beta$$

Since $v -(m+n)\in M$, it follows that $a\in B$.
We can use a similar process to show that any $b\in B$ also lies in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ If $x\in A$, i.e. $x\in \alpha +M$, then there exists some $u\in M$ such that $x=\alpha +u$.
In the part where you have to show that $ A = B $, it is enough to show that $ \alpha - \beta \in M ​​$ (why?)

Comment: Because....$\alpha + m_1 = \beta + m_2$, then $\alpha - \beta = m_2 + m_1$. Since $m_2 + m_1 \in M$, then $\alpha - \beta \in M$ too. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in $M$, then there has to be an element $A \cap B$ that is in $M$!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A=\alpha +M=\{\alpha +m\mid m\in M\}$. $B $ is defined similarly.

Suppose  $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$. Then choose  $y\in A\cap B $. Let $a\in A $. Then $a=\alpha + m$ for some $m\in M $. Since  $y=\alpha+m_1=\beta +m_2$, you can write  $\alpha=\beta +m_2-m_1$. So $a=\beta +m_2-m_1+m $ and hence is in $B$.